# Monte Carlo for Pick 3 Lottery

Tags: r, sampling, montecarlo

This code is not working and I cant understand why.

```
n <- 10000
list <- numeric(n)

for(i in 1:n){
trial1 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
trial2 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
winner <- if(trial1 == trial2) 500 else -1
list[i] <-winner
}
mean(list)
```

Comment: Have you run the code? Where is the `success` defined?

Comment: You are sampling three values (a vector). But you are allowed to put only one value in if condition. If you want to see if the vectors are same or not use  `winner <- if(identical(trial1,trial2)) 500 else -1`.

Comment: I copied it from the problem before and forgot to change the name of the variable. Thanks for replying.

Comment: If you run it, you will know here `trial1` will not equal to `trial2`  because you continue using `sample` function twice. So the `winner` is always `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return 500 only when the values are the same and are in order? Meaning 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3, 1 are different and return -1.

```
n <- 10000

return_result <- function() {
  trial1 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
  trial2 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
  if(all(trial1 == trial2)) 500 else -1
}

mean(replicate(n, return_result()))
```

If 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3, 1 are the same and should return 500 you can `sort` the result before comparing.

```
return_result <- function() {
  trial1 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
  trial2 <- sample(0:9,3, replace = TRUE)
  if(all(sort(trial1) == sort(trial2))) 500 else -1
}

mean(replicate(n, return_result()))
```